# At compiletime do instructions from the file including the entry point function take priority? (C++)

Tags: c++

For example, say you have main.cpp and mustcomefirst.cpp, main.cpp has the entry point function `int main()`

Would I be correct in thinking that compilers (in general) work like this: First it searches for the file with an entry point function in it, then replaces all the include function lines with the code from the file to be included as though `#include mustcomefirst.cpp` wasn't written in the file but the code in the file mustcomefirst.cpp was written there, then it goes to the entry point function and executes consecutively in order from there?

Does including files in a project mean nothing if the file with the entry point function not include that file (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: "mustcomefirst.cpp is told to include 3 files if main.cpp hasn't already included them" - What do you mean by that?

Comment: `#include mustcomefirst.cpp` seem problematic. you wouldn't include an implementation file under normal circumstances, can you clear your question a little more?

Comment: @sftrabbit that was something I forgot to remove as part of an example I failed to think up.

Comment: Generally speaking, each cpp file is compiled without considering the other cpp files to be compiled, and then linked together afterwards (where the entry will actually be set in the executeable, until this point its just a special function)

Comment: Also one should generally not include cpp files into other cpp filer, but rather include header files which defines the services that the corresponding cpp file provides.

Comment: You include header files `.h`, not implementation files `.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, understand at a high level how a C++ program is compiled. If you have three files in your project - `main.cpp`, `foo.cpp`, and `foo.h` - you might compile the project like this:

```
g++ main.cpp foo.cpp
```

These two files are compiled separately. The preprocessor and compiler have no concern about the relationship between these files at all. Preprocessing and compiling `main.cpp` results in an object file and preprocessing and compiling `foo.cpp` results in another object file.

It is only in the last step, the linking step, that the relationships are considered. The *linker* will see that `main` is defined in `main.cpp` and make that the start point of the program. The *linker* will see that inside `main.cpp` there is a call to a function called `foo` that is defined in `foo.cpp` and link those together.

So for each file you pass to the compiler, there are two main steps:

1. Preprocessing - the file is processed in a very primitive way, resulting in preprocessing tokens. Some of those tokens are preprocessing directives which start with a `#`, such as `#include` or `#define`. These directives are executed. Executing a `#include` directive pretty much just copies the contents of the named file into the current file.

   The preprocessing stage results in what is called a *translation unit*.
2. Compilation - the file is then syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated into an object file. This is where it begins to care what exactly your code is meant to be doing and whether it is correct or not. If you attempt to use a name that hasn't been declared, the compiler will tell you off. However, you can often use a name that hasn't been defined, because they may be defined in another translation unit.

   This compilation stage results in the object files.

After this, the resulting object files are combined by resolving references between them. If the object file corresponding to `main.cpp` makes use of a function `foo` that is defined in `foo.cpp` then they are linked together, and so on.

---

To make it clearer, let's take a look at an example. Let's say we have the following source files:

- **main.cpp**

  ```
  #include "foo.h"

  int main() {
    foo();
  }
  ```
- **foo.h**

  ```
  void foo();
  ```
- **foo.cpp**

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "foo.h"

  void foo() {
    std::cout << "Foo!" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

So we pass `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp` to the compiler on the command line. Note that we don't pass header files to the compiler. They are only included by the `.cpp` files. Also note that `.cpp` files generally don't include other `.cpp` files. Each `.cpp` file is compiled separately and linked later.

So after the preprocessing stage, we have two translation units:

- **main.cpp** translation unit

  ```
  void foo();

  int main() {
    foo();
  }
  ```
- **foo.cpp** translation unit

  ```
  // contents of <iostream> here
  void foo();

  void foo() {
    std::cout << "Foo!" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

Notice that the contents of `foo.h` have been copied into each of the files. We now have two completely valid translation units. The first just defines the `main` function and calls the declared-only `foo` function. The second first declares `foo` and then defines it just after.

There translation units are then compiled to produce object files, often called `main.o` and `foo.o`. The linker will then look at certain unresolved references in the files. For instance, it will find the call to `foo` in `main.o` and see that it hasn't yet been defined. So it look through the other object files to see if it can find it, and, sure enough, it finds it in `foo.o`.

Comment: i wish people could stop using the microsoft tech-writer confused terminology. `main` was in a sense a user level entry point in C, but in C++ much user code can be invoked before `main`. the **entry point** of the program is where execution starts, and it has nothing to do with C++ `main`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Changed it to "start point of the program" as the standard says. Any better?

Answer (score 2):

No, the *compiler* in general does not care whether there is an `int main()` in any of your source files or in which source file it is (it *does* care if you have an invalid `main`, such as `void main()`). It most certainly does *not* search all source files for `main`.

When you compile a project with three source files:

`g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp`

each of them is separately translated into object code, just as if you did

`g++ -c file1.cpp; g++ -c file1.cpp; g++ -c file1.cpp`

and *then* linked together by the linker - you could do that manually by

`g++ file1.o file2.o file3.o -o myprogram`.

Here, it's the linker's job to make sure that there is a `main` in your program. If there is none, you'll get an `undefined reference` error, but again, that all happens long after compilation is done.

(Your question becomes ambiguous when you talk about "including files in a project". If you're talking about `#include`, that includes code in one translation unit only. Apart from that, a "project" is not a well-defined concept in C++ but an abstraction that your IDE or build system uses - it mostly means that all source files that you placed in the "project" will be compiled and then linked together as in my example above.)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not care about entry point function. The loader does(http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html).

Very broadly, (for each source file e.g., .cpp/.c) the compiler's task is to:

1. Pre-process the file (including the headers (e.g., .h, .hpp), and replacing the macros).
   At this stage all the header files included in the source file are included (kind of copy-paste) into the source file. All the source files are compiled independently and has nothing to do with what other source files have included/defined.
2. Parses, Converts the program into an abstract syntax tree
3. checks for syntax and type errors.
4. converts the program into intermediate representation (IR).
5. The backend of the compiler takes the IR and optimizes the program.
6. After that the backend converts the optimized IT into target-specific machine code (object files).

----- After this the job of compiler is done.
Besides other tasks, the linker (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) only looks for if there is a `main` function in the program or not. If you dont have a main() function in any of the object files, you'll get linker error. In general, there should be one and only one definition of each function in the set of object files to be linked to generate an executable.

----- The executable is generated by the linker which can be run/executed.

----- To start the execution loader loads the program into main-memory and calls the **main()** function.

To know more just do an objdump on executable you will find a lot of function that gets called before the main.

on linux you can just do

`objdump -d your_main_program > dump_file`